# How to make a ArrayList available in all jsp and servlet pages in web app

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a jsp+servlets web application. I want an ArrayList to be avalable in all jsp and servlet pages which differs for each logged in user. When user logs in to web app, i have some roles assigned to the user, according to the role some permissions are assigned to him inside web application. I mean to say the web application gets transformed according to users role and permissions. For eg some oprations may be only for some roles etc. So i want to run a query when logs in(only once) and save all permissions in array list and get that array list in all jsp and servlet pages. How can i do that.

```
public class Role implements SingleThreadModel{

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    IST ist;
    int user_id;

    public Role(int user_id, Connection connection) {
        try {
            this.user_id = user_id;
            this.connection = connection;
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ist = new IST();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Role.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getPermissionScreens() {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sql = "";
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                myList.add(resultSet.getString("screen_name"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Role.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return myList;
    }

    public List<String> getPermissions(String screen) {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sql = "";
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                myList.add(resultSet.getString("permission_name"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Role.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save that array list in session. Session is specific to user and is valid/alive when user is logged in. Once the user logs out , session his corresponding session will/must be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can store the roleList into the session and play with list as per your requirements. That you can easily access from jsp using

```
<%= request.getAttribute("MyAttribute"); %>
```

Similarly, if you want to set session attribute from jsp, Use jsp Session scope for same.

```
<c:set var="name" value="value" scope="session" />
```

reference link https://www.dineshonjava.com/jsp-scopes-example/

Hope this will help you.